# async: each function never completes

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async.js

I am trying to use the [async library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) to work on a two-dimensional array and process each flattened item. Like this:

```js
import { each } from 'async';

let results: any[] = [];

await each(chats, async (chat) =>
    await each(chat.participants, async (participant) => {

        console.log('Before pause');
        // do something with participant
        results.push(fn(participant));
        await this.timeout(2500);
        console.log('After pause');

      })
);

console.log('Finished');

return results;
```

where

```js
let chats = [
  {
    participants: ['1', '2']
  },
  {
    participants: ['3', '4']
  }
]

timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

However, the `console.log('Finished')` never executes. I have tried lots of variations of `async` and `await` in this code but cannot get it working. I have a working version using pure async/await, but would like to use the async library.

What am I doing wrong?

Note that I do have this working using async/await without using the async library, like this:

```js
await Promise.all(chats.map(
  async (chat) =>
    await Promise.all(chat.participants
      .map(async (participant) => {

        console.log('Before pause');
        // do something with participant
        results.push(fn(participant));
        await this.timeout(2500);
        console.log('After pause');

      })
    )
));

return results;
```

But I would like to use the async library because I am looking to use other of the functions in that library.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd argument of [`each()`](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#each) takes the form of: `function(item, callback) {}`, and the `callback` needs to be invoked when each iteration is done. Note this is not the same `callback` as the optional 3rd argument of `each()`.

The solution is to invoke the callbacks per iteration as shown below:

```js
await each(chats, async (chat, done1 /*1️⃣*/) => {

  await each(chat.participants, async (participant, done2 /*2️⃣*/) => {
    //...
    done2(); /*3️⃣*/
  });

  done1(); /*4️⃣*/
});

console.log("Finished");
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-elgamal-e59m4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fdemo.js&theme=dark)

Comment: Sadly this does not work. The `console.log('Finished')` in your demo is inside the async function, but it does not work outside which it needs to - I need to return the results from this function synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let chats = [
  {
    participants: ['1', '2']
  },
  {
    participants: ['3', '4']
  }
]


chats.forEach(chat =>
     chat.participants.forEach(async (participant) => {

        console.log('Before pause');
        // do something with participant
        await timeout(2500);
        console.log('After pause');
        console.log(participant)

      }));

function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
console.log('Finished');
```

Issues:-

- await only works in async function
- Instead of this.timeout, use with some context or directly in your case. Learn more about behaviour of this in js [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) & [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp)

Comment: The OP is looking for a solution that explicitly uses the `async` library. `forEach` statements are not parallel.

Comment: Saw the toplevel await too. But he labelled it with typescript and typescript 3.8 has top level awaits (in modules, and this is one)

Comment: Yes as @Titulum says, I'd like to use the async library so that the functions can run in parallel. And the `timeout()` correctly substitutes for an asynchronous API call I am making,

Comment: Well, there is nothing like parallel in js(unless multiple process/threads are running), you are just delegating work to next event loop iteration. It is not good to delegate for loop as it is a blocking statement. In this case timeout is statement that should be delegated.

Apart from that, whole point of using promise is to avoid callback.

Anyway if you want to delegate for loop execution to next iteration, setImmediate or process.nextTick(caution use nextTick wisely) can be used.